# Memory leaks in painting a bitmap in eVC++

Tags: memory-leaks, bitmap, windows-ce

I am getting memory leaks in this code. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
CClientDC dc(this); 
CBitmap bmp;
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateBitmap(xOrder, yOrder, 1, 24, (void *)m_lpBits);
bmp.Attach(hBitmap);
CDC dcSource;
dcSource.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc); 
BITMAP bmpInfo;
bmp.GetBitmap(&bmpInfo);
dcSource.SelectObject(&bmp);
CRect rectDest;
GetClientRect(&rectDest);
dc.BitBlt(20, 20, bmpInfo.bmWidth, bmpInfo.bmHeight, &dcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
dc.DeleteDC();
bmp.DeleteObject();
dcSource.DeleteDC();
```

Comment: You are making the standard mistake, you *must* restore the previous selection after you use SelectObject(), before you destroy the DC.

Comment: How can I restore selection? Can you help mi which function should I use?

Comment: Store the return value of the SelectObject(), that's the one you need to restore.  Then call SelectObject() again to restore before you destroy the DC.

Comment: CClientDC dc(this);
 CBitmap bmp;
 bmp.CreateBitmap(xOrder, yOrder, 1, 24, (void *)m_lpBits);
 CDC dcSource;
 dcSource.CreateCompatibleDC(&dc); 
 BITMAP bmpInfo;
 bmp.GetBitmap(&bmpInfo);
 dcSource.SelectObject(&bmp);
 dc.BitBlt(20, 20, bmpInfo.bmWidth, bmpInfo.bmHeight, &dcSource, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
 dc.RestoreDC(-1);
 dc.DeleteDC();
 dcSource.DeleteDC();
 bmp.DeleteObject();

Comment: I think you need to call SaveDC() for RestoreDC() to be effective. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f74yw2h.aspx